# How to change namespace by parameter in KDB+

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I want to change namespace by a given parameter something like below:

```
f:{system "d x"}
```

but this failed, .i.e

```
q)f[".new"]

{system "d x"}

'"

@

.,["\\"]

"d x"
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the function param `x` to your `system` call using join `,`

i.e.

```
q)f:{system "d ",x}

q).ns.v:1
q)f[".ns"]
q.ns)v
1
```